# Set dynamically className on Backbone view render

Tags: backbone.js, render, classname

I've a Backbone view where the className is set dynamically with a function:

```
app.Views.ItemRequestView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName     : 'tr',

    className   : function(){

        var classRow = '';

        if(this.model.getState() == app.Models.Request.status.wait.key) {
            classRow = app.Models.Request.status.wait.color + ' bolder';
        }
        else if(this.model.getState() == app.Models.Request.status.confirm.key){
            classRow = app.Models.Request.status.confirm.color + ' bolder';
        }

        return classRow;
    },
```

When I update the model of the view I trigger a change event who render the view.
The problem is that the className is not recalculate with the render...
How can I recalculate the className when I render the view ?

Anyone have an idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to update your `class` manually after the `render` method. Backbone initializes the `className` of the element of your View only once time during the `_ensureElement` method:

```
_ensureElement: function() {
      if (!this.el) {
        var attrs = _.extend({}, _.result(this, 'attributes'));
        if (this.id) attrs.id = _.result(this, 'id');
        if (this.className) attrs['class'] = _.result(this, 'className');
        var $el = Backbone.$('<' + _.result(this, 'tagName') + '>').attr(attrs);
        this.setElement($el, false);
      } else {
        this.setElement(_.result(this, 'el'), false);
      }
}
```

If you take a look it has a check in case of the element already exists.
Anyway, you can do that manually in your `render` method:

```
render: function(){
   //Your logic
   this.$el.attr('class', _.result(this, 'className'));
}
```

Comment: overkill alert, all you need to do is `this.$el.addClass('classname')` before the view is displayed.

Comment: Unless you're doing something more complicated than adding a class (adding some, toggling some, etc). For that reason it's not overkill, it's robust.