# Refresh Backbone ClassName & Attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

### Question

How can in update Backbone el when re-rendering on model changes?

---

I Currently have an event listener, listening to model changes like this.

`this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);`

This will then re-render the view correctly however the className & attributes are not updated to reflect the model changes, they look like this.

```
className: function()
{
    var childClassName  = ( null === this.model.get('parent_id') ? '' : ' list-item-child' ),
        parentClassName = ( false == this.model.get('parent') ? '' : ' list-item-parent');

    return 'list-item' + childClassName + parentClassName;
},

attributes: function()
{
    return {
        'data-id': this.model.get('id'),
        'data-parent': this.model.get('parent_id')
    }
},
```

Comment: maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330877/set-dynamically-classname-on-backbone-view-render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update yourself, for instance:

```
onRender: function(){

  this.$el.removeClass().addClass(this.className());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `className` is set at the view creation, when you rerender the view it wont be updated.

If you have no other solution, maybe this solution can help you :

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', function() {
    this._ensureElement();
    this.render();
    this.delegateEvents();
});
```